# How do you use SQLExecDirect?

Tags: sql, c

I saw this code in another post and I'm not sure how it works. I've never used SQL in C/C++, and I'm just trying to insert into a test_table, kind of like the code below. can someone walk me through this?  it executes an empty string, with no handle, and sprintf is missing the str param.. is it printing to the char sql[1000] variable somehow?

If this code is wrong, can someone explain how I'd use SQLExecdirect to insert some variables into a table?

```
for (n = 0; n < 10000; n++) {
    char sql[1000];
    sprintf("insert into mytable (cola, colb) values(%d,%d)", n, n);
    SQLExecDirect(sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this code is wrong. The third line should be

```
sprintf(sql, "insert into mytable (cola, colb) values(%d,%d)", n, n);
```

There's the code breakdown:

`char sql[1000];` creates an empty string called `sql` which is 1000 characters long.

`sprintf(sql, "insert into mytable (cola, colb) values(%d,%d)", n, n);` populates this string with the text and replaces each `%d` with the value of `n`.

`SQLExecDirect(sql);` executes this SQL command.

In other words, the following SQL queries will get executed:

```
insert into mytable (cola, colb) values(0,0)
insert into mytable (cola, colb) values(1,1)
insert into mytable (cola, colb) values(2,2)
...
insert into mytable (cola, colb) values(9999,9999)
```

Comment: it makes much more sense with sprintf(sql... instead of missing the handler.. I didn't pick up on that. Thanks. Makes sense.

Comment: I get error: too few arguments to function ‘SQLExecDirect’
presumably because it is missing a handler?

Comment: Here's the [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713611(v=vs.85).aspx) describing how this function is used. It takes three arguments, so you're definitely not using it right. I think this problem, however, is beyond the scope of this question.